# Can an addon be made aware of username/process owner

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

Ok, so I'm guessing the answer to this question is *no* (sensing privacy issues here), but let's check anyway.

Is it possible to read the username of the *computer user* (think SSO)? This could perhaps be read from the owner of the Firefox process.

I'm not really seeing anything about it in the SDK docs, and searching for username just gives me a bunch of password managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

api-utils/environment provides access to the user's shell environment variables:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/api-utils/environment.html

Here is some basic usage:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/156370/latest/

Depending on what info you need, you can run system commands with the priviledges of Firefox itself to get info from, say, the Windows registry. You should be aware that malicious use of code like this would not be allowed when your add-on is reviewed by the Mozilla Addons site.

Comment: If one wants to access the Windows registry then there are [better ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessing_the_Windows_Registry_Using_XPCOM) than to run system commands. But getting the `USERNAME` or `LOGNAME` environment variable (for Windows and Unix respectively) should be sufficient anyway.

Comment: This is an internal tool used within our company, so it will never reach Mozilla. What I do now is promt the user for username, and check that against the ActiveDirectory. But if it would be possible to do without prompting the users, I'm sure they would be happy.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I will do some tests, but that seems to do the trick. I'm not interested in the registry, just the username